# profiling Monty Hall code with aprof package

Tags: r, performance, memory-management

I have written `R` code for the Monty Hall problem.  The code works as far as I can tell.  However, I also was using the `aprof` package to try to reduce speed and memory requirements of the code.  I was able to reduce speed by 50%, but I cannot get the memory profiling feature of the `aprof` package to work.  Thank you for any advice or assistance in resolving this error.

First I describe the Monty Hall problem:

Three doors are presented to a contestant.  One door hides a nice prize.  Two doors hide a bad prize.  Contestant does not know what is behind each door.  Contestant selects a door.  Host opens one of the two doors not selected by the contestant.  Host does not open the door hiding the nice price.  Next, host asks contestant if contestant wishes to keep door initially selected or switch to the one remaining closed door not initially selected by contestant.  What should contestant do?  Answer: contestant should ALWAYS switch doors.  This is because contestant initially has 33% chance to win and 67% chance to lose.  Switching doors increasing probability of winning to 67%.

Here is the `R` code, which I believe works.

```
library(aprof)
set.seed(1234)
foo <- function(N) {

     game.interations  <- 10000
     contestant.action <- rep(NA, game.interations)
     game.result       <- rep('lose', game.interations)

     for(i in 1:game.interations) {

          door <- c(0,0,0)
          door[sample(3, 1)] = 1            # assign nice prize to a door
                                            # door  with '1' has  nice prize
                                            # doors with '0' have bad  prize
          initial.pick <- sample(3, 1)      # initial contestant action
          not.picked   <- c(1:3)[-initial.pick]
          door.opened.by.host <- not.picked[1]
          if(door[initial.pick   ]==1) door.opened.by.host = not.picked[sample(2,1)]
          if(door[  not.picked[1]]==1) door.opened.by.host = not.picked[2]
          contestant.action[i] <- sample(c('k', 's'), 1)
          second.pick <- ifelse(contestant.action[i] == 'k', initial.pick, 
                         not.picked[which(not.picked!=door.opened.by.host)])
          if(door[second.pick]==1) game.result[i] = 'win'
     }

x <- table(contestant.action , game.result)         # examine probability of 
                                                    # winning by action 
prop.table(x)

}

foo(N)

#                      game.result
# contestant.action   lose    win
#          k (keep)   0.3293 0.1613
#          s (switch) 0.1705 0.3389
```

Here is where the `aprof` code begins.  From this point onward the code is taken from the package documentation.  The code in this section also seems to work correctly and identifies time required by each line of the function `foo`.

```
## save function to a source file and reload
dump("foo",file="foo.R")
source("foo.R")

## create file to save profiler output
tmp<-tempfile()

## Profile the function
Rprof(tmp,line.profiling=TRUE)
foo(1e4)
Rprof(append=FALSE)

## Create a aprof object
fooaprof<-aprof("foo.R",tmp)

## display basic information, summarize and plot the object
fooaprof
summary(fooaprof)
plot(fooaprof)

# another plot
profileplot(fooaprof)
```

Here is where the memory profiling code begins.  The line that returns an error is identified below.

```
## To continue with memory profiling:
## enable memory.profiling=TRUE
Rprof(tmp,line.profiling=TRUE,memory.profiling=TRUE)
foo(1e4)
Rprof(append=FALSE)

#
# This line returns the error message below
#
## Create a aprof object
fooaprof<-aprof("foo.R",tmp)
#
# Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("sm_v_heap", "lrg_v_heap", "mem_in_node" : 
# 'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [0]
#

## display basic information, and plot memory usage
fooaprof
plot(fooaprof)
```

Here are the contents of the file that I think the `aprof` package is attempting to read when it returns the error, but I am not sure.  Note that this is a hidden file:

```
memory profiling: line profiling: sample.interval=20000
#File 1: foo.R
:153316:554084:15881544:162:1#22 "foo" 
:150595:494927:15084104:869:1#26 "foo" 
:149818:473956:14839440:908:1#12 "sample" 1#12 "foo" 
:147827:430136:14250768:879:"sample" 1#16 "foo" 
:154551:576315:16254896:864:1#24 "foo" 
:151678:512463:15404032:896:"is.numeric" "sample" 1#12 "foo" 
:150598:488049:15083040:929:"length" "sample" 1#12 "foo" 
:146904:403852:13989752:857:"sample.int" "sample" 1#12 "foo" 
:146035:384446:13729968:919:"sample" 1#24 "foo" 
:156862:629525:16944760:955:"sample.int" "sample" 1#24 "foo" 
:154543:577567:16250584:905:1#24 "foo" 
:150690:595793:15020264:942:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a bug (incomplete regex syntax). Thanks for reporting this. The bug has been fixed in version 0.3.2. available from [github](https://github.com/MarcoDVisser/aprof). It will be uploaded to CRAN soon.