# How can I print how long it takes my code to run every Nth line in R?

Tags: r

I have tried using system.time() so far, but I do not know how to integrate that into printing out the amount of time it took to run every nth line where n is whatever number I make it.

Comment: Take a look at the aprof package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119075/profiling-monty-hall-code-with-aprof-package

Answer (score 0):

The `tictoc` package may provide the tool you are looking for.

Example

```
# install.packages("tictoc")
library(tictoc)

tic()
for(i in 1:1000) { 
  x <- rnorm(1e5)
}
toc()

tic()
for(i in 1:1000) { 
  x <- rexp(1e5)
}
toc()
```